# tensorflow model attention_ocr occur oom error when training by use gtx1070

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

my gpu is gtx1070,when i want to train attention_ocr model ,the log occur error
ResourceExhaustedError:OOM when allocating tensor with shape

the document say has tested with gtx980,so my gtx1070 is ok in theory。

Comment: Please provide an actual question and enough details for somebody to help. If you want to debug memory issues, take a look at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/profiler and specifically at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/g3doc/profile_memory.md

Comment: thanks for answer，i had solve this question with 1080ti，the memory is 11G enough to training